# Возведение в степень по модулю. Большие числа в си

Tags: c

Здравствуйте! Мне необходимо вычислить:

```
2147483647^2147483647%2147483648;
2147483647=2^(31)-1;
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как реализовать подобное на с?

Comment: А что Вы понимаете под "чистым си"? Есть библиотеки, для "чистого си"... Только я подозреваю, что тупое возведение в степень тут не требуется...

Comment: это лабораторная работа и нам нужно ее сдавать только на си,не на с++

Comment: А причём тут си? Задача на математическую сообразительность. Поскольку степень нечётная, то там должен быть результат "-1"/ Или 2147483647 . Но могу и ошибаться -- голова плохо варит.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Все очень просто. Понятно, что если умножать числа и потом взять по модулю, то для этого нужна будет длинная арифметика. А число выйдет приличное (более 66,571 миллиардов знаков). Поэтому применим трюк - будет после каждого умножения брать по модулю. То есть, код где то такой (схематически)

```
a = 2147483647;
m = 2147483648;
for (i = 0; i < 2147483647; i++) {
   r *=a;
   r %= m;
}
```

Но здесь своя незадача. Работать это дело будет не быстро.

Здесь в бой вступает [быстрое возведение в степень](http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C). Оно работает очень быстро.

Но есть ещё один подводный камень. Дело в том, что число то большое и вполне будет переполнение. Здесь можно поступить двояко. либо взять 64битное и все сделать, либо, учитывая, что все равно нужно брать по модулю 2 в 32, использовать следствия переполнения (оно будет работать нам на руку).

Вариант с 64битными переменными

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define int64 long long int

int64 st(int64 a, int64 b, int64 m) {
    int64 r = 1;
    while (b) {
        if (b & 1) {
            r *= a;
            r %= m;
        }
        a *= a;
        a %= m;
        b >>=1;
    }
    return r;
}

int main()
{
    int64 a = 2147483647;
    int64 m = 2147483648;
    int64 r = st(a,a,m);
    printf("%lld\n", r);
    return 0;
}
```

Вариант с 32битными

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int st(unsigned int a, unsigned int b) {
    unsigned int r = 1;
    while (b) {
        if (b & 1) {
            r *= a;
        }
        a *= a;
        b >>=1;
    }
    return r;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int a = 2147483647;
    unsigned int r = st(a,a);
    printf("%d\n", r);
    return 0;
}
```

p.s все компилировал в gcc строкой `gcc test.c  -Wall -pedantic -std=c99` на 64 битной системе. Оба варианта выдали 2147483647. На первый взгляд странно. Но потом, взяв обычный листик бумаги, я убедился, что 2147483647 * 2147483647 % 2147483648 равно 1. Отсюда напрашивается вывод, что для  (2147483647 ^ a) % 2147483648 равно 1 для всех четных a. и 2147483647 для всех нечетных.

Comment: @KoVadim: то, что `2147483647 * 2147483647 % 2147483648 == 1` не удивительно, т. к. `2147483647 == -1 (mod 21474836478)`, а значит, `2147483647 * 2147483647 == (-1) * (-1) (mod 21474836478)`.

Comment: @VladD я знаю, что если возвести в квадрат число, двоичное представление которого заканчивается на `n` 1, то в результирующее число будет заканчиваться на `n-1` ноль и 1. Словом "удивительно" я просто хотел немного интриги добавить:)

Comment: @KoVadim: окей, интрига засчитана. (Я попался, например, что видно из комментария.)