# Возведение в степень по модулю без переполнений

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, overflow, переполнение

**Как возвести число в степень по модулю без переполнений в умножениях со скоростью не хуже бинарного возведения в степень, не используя расширения компиляторов?**

Все алгоритмы, что я нашёл в интернете, имеют переполнение, если числа близки к максимально поддерживаемым (64битный unsigned long long у меня). Например, [отсюда](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/binary_pow):

```
int binpow (int a, int n) {
    int res = 1;
    while (n) {
        if (n & 1)
            res *= a;
        a *= a;
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return res;
}
```

при максимальных типах выражения `res = res * a % mod;` и `a = a * a % mod` дают ULL "переполнение" и результат неверный.

[Пример кода на этом сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/322238), выдающий неправильные результаты.

Единственный рабочий вариант пока, это вместо умножений аналогично бинарному возведению в степень использовать бинарное умножение (складываем по модулю, пока не получим результат), но тогда возведение в степень работает очень медленно и переполнение всё ещё может произойти в самом сложении (хотя для моих данных этого достаточно, так что основной минус в скорости).

Ну или длинная арифметика, не тестил скорость, но думаю, что будет не очень быстро.

Быстрый + без переполнений вариант - использовать встроенные 128битные типы, поддерживаемые некоторыми компиляторами. Минус - не по стандарту.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать тип `double` или `long double`. Они вмещают гораздо большие значения, чем `long long`. Вот [здесь](https://konspekta.net/stydopediaru/baza5/466828065265.files/image016.jpg) можно посмотреть из диапазон

Comment: @Стас тогда потеря точности будет, что тоже даст неверный результат. Да и по скорости надо потестить, думаю будет значительно медленнее

Comment: Главное - `mod` какое? такое, что `mod*mod` дает переполнение?...

Comment: @Harry да, все 3 числа в квадрате могут давать переполнение. Однако, конкретно на моих данных, `2*a`, `2*n`, `2*mod` не могут дать переполнение, т.е. 1 раз сложить по модулю само с собой можно любое число

Comment: Тогда надо искать 128-битную быструю реализацию вычисления остатка... Умножение пишется быстро, а вот деление... :(

Comment: За что минус вопросу?

Comment: @Harry думаете, без длинной арифметики нельзя избежать переполнения никак?

Comment: Это не мой :) Кстати, а компилятор у вас какой? Компиляторозависимое решение годится?

Comment: @Harry `gcc` и `clang` последние. Если вы про встроенные 128-битные типы, то хотелось бы оставаться в рамках стандарта :)

Comment: О них. Если без них - то не вижу другого способа, кроме как писать руками переносимое умножение и вычисление остатка. Imho, само собой...

Comment: Вам нужно смотреть теорию сравнений. a=b(mod p) и a^2=b*a(mod p)

Comment: Еще как вариант разложить число по степеням простых чисел

Comment: @becouse как использовать первое в этой задаче? Как сделать второе с хорошей скоростью?

Comment: @вася первое я даже расписал. Нужна степень по модулю вот пример. Второе с помощью списка простых чисел это стандартный алгоритм.

Comment: @becouse было бы неплохо, если бы вы написали ответ с кодом.

Answer (score 3):

Всё очень просто ;) Быстрое возведение в степень. Умножение по модулю без переполнений. Сумма модульная без ошибок. И вуаля : быстро и правильно. Не используются операции умножения и деления. Сложность алгоритма A ^ P mod M : O(Log(P)*Log(M)). Пример на Си:

```
// gcc-9 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Winline -std=c11 -Os pow_mod.c -o pow_mod
# include <stdio.h>
static  inline  unsigned  long  long  int sum_mod (
  unsigned  long  long  int x ,
  unsigned  long  long  int y ,
  unsigned  long  long  int m ) {
  if ( m - x > y )
    return  x + y ;
  return  y - ( m - x ) ; }

// ( x * y ) mod m , 0 < x < m , y < m
// ( 5 * y ) mod m = ( y mod m ) + ( ( ( y * 2 ) mod m ) * 2 ) mod m
unsigned  long  long  int mul_mod (
  unsigned  long  long  int x ,
  unsigned  long  long  int y ,
  unsigned  long  long  int m ) {
  if  ( x > y ) {
    unsigned  long  long  int tmp = x ;
    x = y ;
    y = tmp ; }
  // x <= y
  unsigned  long  long  int res = 0 ;
  unsigned  long  long  int iy  = y ;
  while ( x ) {
    if ( x & 1 )
      res = sum_mod ( res , iy , m ) ;
    iy  = sum_mod  ( iy , iy , m ) ;
    x >>= 1 ; }
  return  res ; }

// ( x ^ n ) mod m , x < m , n > 0 , m > 0
// ( x ^ 5 ) mod m == ( ( x mod m ) * ( ( ( ( ( x ^ 2 ) mod m ) ) ^ 2 ) mod m ) ) mod m
unsigned  long  long  int pow_mod (
  unsigned  long  long  int x ,
  unsigned  long  long  int n ,
  unsigned  long  long  int m ) {
  unsigned  long  long  int res = 1 ;
  while ( n ) {
    if ( n & 1 )
      res = mul_mod ( res , x , m ) ;
    x = mul_mod ( x , x , m ) ;
    n >>= 1 ; }
  return res  ; }

int main(){
  printf("sizeof(unsigned  long  long  int)*8=%zu\n",sizeof(unsigned  long  long  int)*8);
  unsigned  long  long  int res ;
  res = pow_mod(10,10,11);
  printf("10^10 mod 11 = %llu\n",res);
  res = pow_mod(100,100,111);
  printf("100^100 mod 111 = %llu\n",res);
  res = pow_mod(2147483647,2147483647,2147483648);
  printf("2147483647^2147483647 mod 2147483648 = %llu\n",res);
  res = pow_mod(12345678900987654321ULL,12345678900987654321ULL,12345678901234567890ULL);
  printf("12345678900987654321^12345678900987654321 mod 12345678901234567890 = %llu\n",res);
  }
```

Результат :

```
> ./pow_mod 
sizeof(unsigned  long  long  int)*8=64
10^10 mod 11 = 1
100^100 mod 111 = 100
2147483647^2147483647 mod 2147483648 = 2147483647
12345678900987654321^12345678900987654321 mod 12345678901234567890 = 566503238319246891
```

Проверяем :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда нужно будет использовать длинные числа (4096 битные например) то алгоритму нужны будут операции +,-,>(больше),=(set присвоение),&1(oddp нечётность), >>=1(деление пополам). Это простые функции линейной сложности. А если использовать другой приём: использовать умножение и потом деление, то это приведёт к громодкости кода (если оно будет ваше) и замедлению (в классических алгоритмах сложность порядка O(n^2)).

Comment: Разве это не *вместо умножений аналогично бинарному возведению в степень использовать бинарное умножение*, а значит *тогда возведение в степень работает очень медленно*?

Comment: Скорость очень хорошая. Посчитайте, проверьте. O(Log(степень)*Log(число)) @вася

Comment: А у простого бинарного возведения в степень `O(log(степень))`.

Comment: Все проблемы начнутся при умножении больших чисел. Сложность будет расти порядка `O((бит^2)/1000)`. Тогда время будет `O(log(степень)*(бит^2)/1000)`. Практически разница с `O(Log(степень)*бит)` будет незаметна, но в перспективе и в лёгкости алгоритма (умножение займет всю страницу) логарифмическая сложность лучше. @вася

Answer (score 0):

Можно проще и быстрее, учитывая что суммы не переполняются:

```
#include <cstdio>

unsigned  long  long   int mul_mod (
  unsigned  long  long  int x ,
  unsigned  long  long  int y ,
  unsigned   long  long  int m ) {
  if  ( x > y ) {
    unsigned  long  long  int tmp = x ;
    x = y ;
    y = tmp ; }
  unsigned  long  long  int res = 0 ;
  unsigned  long  long  int iy  = y ;
  while ( x ) {
    if ( x & 1 )
      res =  (res  + iy) % m ;
    iy  = (iy + iy) % m;
    x >>= 1 ; }
  return  res ; }

unsigned  long  long  int pow_mod (
  unsigned  long  long  int x ,
  unsigned   long  long  int n ,
  unsigned  long  long  int m ) {
  unsigned  long  long  int res = 1 ;
  while ( n ) {
    if ( n & 1 )
      res = mul_mod ( res ,   x , m ) ;
    x = mul_mod  ( x , x , m ) ;
    n >>= 1 ; }
  return res  ; }

int main(){
  unsigned  long  long  int res ;
  res = pow_mod(10,10,11);
  printf("10^10 mod 11 = %llu\n",res);
  res = pow_mod(100,100,111);
  printf("100^100 mod 111 = %llu\n",res);
  res = pow_mod(2147483647,2147483647,2147483648);
  printf("2147483647^2147483647 mod 2147483648 = %llu\n",res);
  }
```