# Возведение в степень по модулю не проходит все тесты

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

https://www.eolymp.com/ru/problems/5336

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    int a, n, rezult = 1, i;
    int chislo;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> n;
    chislo = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        rezult *= a;
    }
    chislo = rezult % 1000000007;
    cout << chislo;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ловите переполнение, берите по модулю при каждом умножении, а само умножение делайте в ll

Comment: попробуйте мой ответ в https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1146863/Возведение-в-степень-по-модулю-без-переполнений/1148275#1148275 Может понравиться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Бинарное возведение в степень и «очень длинная арифметика»:) взятие mod от длинноного числа.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
using namespace std; 

const long long mod = 1000000007;
 
long long int  powLL(long long int  x, long long int  n) 
{ 
   long long int  result = 1; 
    x %= mod;
    if(x == 0) return 0;
    while (n)
    { 
        if (n & 1)  result = (result * x) % mod; 
        n /= 2; 
        x = (x * x) % mod; 
    } 
    return result; 
} 
 
long long int  powStrings(string sa, string sb) 
{
    long long int  a = 0, b = 0;  
    for (int i = 0; i < sa.size(); i++) a = (a * 10 + (sa[i] - 0x30)) % mod; 
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.size(); i++) b = (b * 10 + (sb[i] - 0x30)) % mod; 
    return powLL(a, b); 
} 
 
  
 
int main(void) 
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(nullptr);

    string sa, sb; cin >> sa >> sb;
    cout << powStrings(sa, sb) << endl; 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

Comment: А зачем это, гм... легкое извращение с чтением строк и переводом их в числа? Почему бы из просто не прочесть как два числа? Да, и толку от первых двух строк в `main` при таком вводе-выводе - чтении двух чисел и выводе одного - никакого...

Comment: @Harry входные данные большие num и exp от 0 до 10^1000. Если не использовать как Вы сказали гм будет переполнение переменных)

Comment: @Андрей Ерунда - потому что для таких данных все равно они не разместятся в `long long int`. Нет никакого смысла читать строки и переводить их в обычный тип, в который можно прочесть и так...

Comment: @Harry а как можно их прочитать иначе?

Comment: @Андрей `long long int  a, b; cin >> a >> b;`

Comment: @Harry unsigned long long int tmp = pow(10, 1000); cout << tmp << endl; // 0 переполнение

Comment: @Harry в задании входные данные [0, 10^1000], int64_t или uint64_t не влезет

Comment: @Андрей Да, согласен, не обратил внимания на работу по модулю в `powStrings`, каюсь...